# How to Scrape Fidelity.com with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the stock symbol from this page:

`https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria=294100102&submit=Search.`

In the page response, I see:

```
<tr><td height="20" nowrap=""><font class="smallfont">ENZO BIOCHEM ORD SHS</font></td>
            <td align="center" width="20%"><font><a href="/webxpress/get_quote?QUOTE_TYPE=&amp;SID_VALUE_ID=ENZ">ENZ</a></font></td>
            <td><font>&nbsp;</font></td>
             <td><font></font></td></tr>    
        </tbody></table></td></tr>
```

And I just need to print `ENZ`.

How would I do this using BeautifulSoup? Also, is there an easier way (doesn't look like there's an API, but I might be wrong)?

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria="
cusip = "294100102"
url = base_url + cusip + "&submit=Search"

# Set Soup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all("table")[0]
rows = table.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
    company = row.find_all("td", class_="smallfont")
    print(company)
```

Comment: The class is set on a font element, not a td element. You're searching to find all td's with a class 'smallfont'

Comment: I see. When I set it to "font" instead of "td" element, it only returns the full company name so I guess the font element is different for the full name vs the symbol. So what element should I search for if I only want ````"ENZ"````?

Comment: If you are open to use something other than beautiful soup, I can solve your problem. xpath is a great way to find elements nested deep down in a node tree. But sadly beautiful soup doesn't support searching by xpath

Comment: ENZ is inside  `a` in `td` maybe with somethign `row.select("td a")`

Comment: @MarekMaszay ```row.select("td a)``` didn't seem to work

Comment: @Shuvojit I haven't used it before but I would be open to trying it. In case it matters, long-term goal is to loop through a list of CUSIP IDs and extract the stock symbol from the resulting page response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using `font a` should work as css selector.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://quotes.fidelity.com/mmnet/SymLookup.phtml?reqforlookup=REQUESTFORLOOKUP&productid=mmnet&isLoggedIn=mmnet&rows=50&for=stock&by=cusip&criteria=294100102&submit=Search')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('font a').text)
```

An alternative, which seems quite robust, is to use [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector with contains operator to target the `a` tag `href`

```
soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]').text
```

Before attempting to access `.text` it is usually a good idea to set the matched element to a variable and test if `None`

For example,

```
var = soup.select_one('[href*=SID_VALUE_ID]')
if var is None:
    print('Not found')
else:
    print(var.text)
```